# PEAR Error code list

Tags: php, error-handling, pear

This question has been asked before, but not answered. Is there a list anywhere of PEAR error codes?

I have a server/client application and the client needs to know about all possible error messages that could be produced by the server, so I need to make sure all errors that could possibly be raised using the PEAR Mail package are handled properly by my client app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is none. The only way to get a complete list is grepping the source code for `PEAR::raiseError`.